# Filtrando dados dos sensores de aceleração e magnético no Android

Tags: java, android, c++, filtro, dsp

Tenho um [player](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid) open source para Android há algum tempo. Meses atrás criei um visualizador de áudio (do tipo daqueles com barras e cores) onde o usuário podia interagir, simulando uma realidade aumentada (a visualização aparenta estar "ao redor" da pessoa, conforme a pessoa move o dispositivo).

Depois de alguns testes, percebi que os dados dos sensores magnéticos e de aceleração oscilam muito (como é de se esperar em sensores analógicos), então eu uso um filtro passa-baixa de primeira ordem para suavizar o movimento. Até aí, sem novidades.

Acontece que ao assistir [este clipe da Björk](https://youtu.be/gQEyezu7G20) no YouTube do dispositivo, percebi que ele segue o mesmo princípio, e oferece uma experiência em 360 graus.

Contudo, eu reparei que o movimento no YouTube não fica tão suavizado/lento como no meu visualizador, mas não "treme" quando solto em uma superfície lisa. Em outras palavras: os dados crus, logo meu visualizador, oscilam muito quando o dispositivo está em repouso, por isso precisei filtrar, e o movimento acaba ficando meio lento. Mas no YouTube, não há "tremores" quando o dispositivo está na mesma superfície em descanso, porém ele responde bem mais rápido do que o meu visualizador.

Como pode-se ver no [código onde trato os dados dos sensores](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid/blob/master/jni/GLSoundParticle.h) (função `onSensorData`, a partir da linha 286), estou utilizando o seguinte filtro:

```
coefNew = (0.03125f / 16.0f) * delta;
coefOld = 1.0f - coefNew;
```

Observações:

- `coefNew` é usado na entrada (x) e `coefOld` na saída anterior (y)
- `delta` é o intervalo, em milissegundos, entre o quadro anterior e o atual
- `/ 16.0f * delta` serve para ajustar o coeficiente dependendo da taxa de fps

Já tentei "brincar" com o coeficiente, e se eu aumento seu valor, o movimento passa a responder mais rápido, mas os tremores voltam (como é de se esperar).

Mesmo estando em C++, me baseei no código da classe `SensorManager`, do próprio Android, para gerar a matriz de transformação linear: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/hardware/SensorManager.java

Daí vem minha pergunta: Existe outro tipo de filtro / técnica que possa ser utilizado nessa situação? Alguém sabe como o YouTube consegue aquele movimento com resposta rápida, mas que não "treme" (existe outro método de aquisição de dados do Android para criar a matriz de transformação linear)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de muita procura consegui eleger os top 3 links que mais me elucidaram nessa questão:

- [Using Android gyroscope instead of accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13679568/3569421)
- [Indoor Positioning System based on Gyroscope and Accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499959/indoor-positioning-system-based-on-gyroscope-and-accelerometer)
- [Código-fonte do SensorService - AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-release/services/sensorservice/)

Basicamente descobri que:

- Os dados do sensor magnético realmente são bastante ruidosos em todos os dispositivos, bem mais ruidosos do que os dados provenientes do sensor de gravidade/aceleração
- Não utilizar o sensor magnético envolve ter que utilizar o giroscópio, que também é bastante ruidoso, e, por sua vez, acaba recaindo em ter utilizar um [Filtro de Kalman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) para estimar e filtras os valores retornados pelo sensor
- Utilizar outros filtros passa-baixa de 2ª ordem (ou de ordem maior), como [Filtros Butterworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter), entre outros, realmente não remove o tipo de ruído presente nos dados do sensor magnético (testei filtros de diversas ordens, com diferentes frequências de corte, todos sem o resultado esperado)
- Utilizar [Holt-Winters double exponential smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Double_exponential_smoothing) (também com referências [aqui](http://www.it.iitb.ac.in/~praj/acads/seminar/04329008_ExponentialSmoothing.pdf)) ou deixa passar muito o ruído quando o dispositivo está efetivamente parado, ou cria um *overshoot* indesejado
- Utilizar sensores do tipo [TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) e [TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR) realmente não resolve, pois os dados que formam o [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) devolvido em [SensorEvent.values](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) não são filtrados pelo Android
- Utilizar o sensor do tipo [TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR) é muito arriscado, apesar dele não utilizar internamente o sensor magnético, pois testei em alguns dispositivos "topo de linha", com API 18+, e esse sensor não estava presente ([SensorManager.getDefaultSensor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getDefaultSensor(int)) retornava `null`)
- Não é possível encontrar o código-fonte do YouTube tão facilmente :)

Assim, desisti e comecei a fazer algumas simulações no Excel utilizando dados reais obtidos do sensor magnético durante a utilização do aparelho, como no gráfico a seguir, que mostra o dispositivo em repouso, depois o dispositivo sendo girado, e por fim, girado de volta, quase para a posição inicial:

[image: Dados reais obtidos do sensor magnético]

Decidi, então, utilizar um filtro passa-baixa com corte adaptativo. Quanto menor fosse a alteração do valor, com relação ao valor anterior, menor seria a frequência de corte (produzindo uma resposta mais lenta), e quanto maior fosse a alteração, maior a frequência de corte (produzindo uma resposta mais rápida).

O gráfico abaixo mostra o coeficiente utilizado com o filtro passa-baixa. Ele segue a seguinte equação quadrática (`absDelta` representa o valor absoluto da diferença entre o valor anterior do sensor e o valor atual):

```
coeficiente = (0.05 × absDelta²) + (0.025 × absDelta)
```

[image: Reposta do coeficiente do filtro passa-baixa]

O valor final limitado a `0.15`, produzindo o seguinte código:

```
absDelta = valorAtual - valorAnterior;
coefNew = (absDelta >= 1.5f ?
              0.15f :
              ((0.05f * absDelta * absDelta) + (0.025f * absDelta))
          ) * 0.0625f * delta;
coefOld = 1.0f - coefNew;
```

Observações:

- `coefNew` é usado na entrada (x) e `coefOld` na saída anterior (y)
- `delta` é o intervalo, em milissegundos, entre o quadro anterior e o atual
- `0.0625f * delta` serve para ajustar o coeficiente dependendo da taxa de fps

Por fim, o resultado obtido com essa técnica é como o mostrado no gráfico abaixo, onde as linhas pretas mostram o valor filtrado:

[image: Dados filtrados do sensor magnético]

Esse filtro é aplicado de maneira independente para cada um dos eixos x, y e z.

O código completo já está no [repositório do projeto](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid/blob/master/jni/GLSoundParticle.h), dentro da função `onSensorData()` (atualmente na linha 286), mas hoje (2015-07-07) ainda não está na versão do aplicativo que se encontra na [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.carlosrafaelgn.fplay).

Fiz diversos testes e o resultado me agradou bastante. Ele responde rápido quando movo o dispositivo depressa, e filtra boa parte dos ruídos quando deixo o dispositivo parado.

Cheguei a utilizar outras funções no lugar da parábola mostrada acima, como uma [Interpolação de Hermite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation) ou outras funções cúbicas, mas a resposta ficava ou muito devagar, ou o ruído ficava muito aparente. Ainda assim, cheguei a outra parábola que também pode ser utilizada, mas que "para meu gosto" deixou a resposta muito lenta para pequenas variações reais do dispositivo:

```
coeficiente = (0.065 × absDelta²) + (0.0025 × absDelta)
```

Para os dados do sensor de gravidade/aceleração, mantive o filtro passa-baixas de primeira ordem, pois os dados não são se mostraram tão ruidosos quanto os do sensor magnético:

```
coefNew = (0.140625f / 16.0f) * delta;
coefOld = 1.0f - coefNew;
```